# Simple Xml - Указать тип

Tags: php, xml

```
   <enclosure url="https://test.ru/shared/files/201902/1_878072.jpg" length="234792" type="image/jpeg"/>
   <enclosure url="https://test.ru/shared/files/201902/1_878141.mp4" length="13918809" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Как получить изображение, когда в XML один enclosure я знаю

```
$xml->channel->item[1]->enclosure->attributes($url);
```

Но что делать когда **enclosure** 2? Как указать тип **type="image/jpeg"**?

Comment: Поитерироваться по `enclosure`, у каждого проверить нужный аттрибут. Или xpath.